# Changing UIImageView’s image doesn’t work

Tags: ios, swift, struct, uiimage

I've got a struct, which contains a static variable called userProfileImage, this struct is in a view controller called UserProfilePage.swift, here is the code:

```
struct UserProfile {
    static let userProfileImage = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profilePicture"))
}

class UserProfilePage: UIViewController {
    // Some code that sets the userProfileImage to another image
}
```

The following code is in another swift file that has a struct called Downloads:

```
struct Downloads {

    guard let profilePicURL = URL(string: profilePictureString) else {
        UserProfile.userProfileImage.image = UIImage(named: "profilePicture")
        print("Profile picture set to default profile picture")
        return
    }
    // Some code
}
```

When `profilePicURL` is not empty, some code gets executed, but when it is empty (equal to `""`), the code inside the else block gets executed. The problem is that the profile picture doesn't change, it just executes the print statement inside the else block. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Check if `UIImage(named: "profilePicture")` is returning an image object

Comment: I've done that in other view controllers and it does return an object

Comment: "userProfileImage" is static let , how can you assign it new value.

Comment: @Vikky He is changing its property not the entire object.

Comment: Yes what Cerlin said @Vikky

Comment: @CerlinBoss ya my bad, I just realised after adding my comment.

Comment: Image doesn't change because you are again setting "profilePicture" same image.

Comment: Oh my bad, there is some more code in UserProfilePage.swift that changes the image to another image, so once it's changed I need to go back to the original image in the Downloads.swift file. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Are you sure  that `UserProfile.userprofileImage` is the control being displayed?  Can you see the image change in other circumstances?  Perhaps show the code where you add it to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, it does work when I try it on the same view controller (UserProfilePage.swift), it doesn't, when I try to change from another view controller

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to change your **userProfileImage**. This Should be a var instead of **static let.

You can use **if let** statement with an async call in your code. Please try the following code.

```
    let profilePictureString = "http://SOME URl STRING.."
    if let profilePicURL = URL(string: profilePictureString){
        // Plcae Your Network Code Here.
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UserProfile.userProfileImage.image = UIImage(named: "profilePicture")
            print("Profile picture set to default profile picture")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer but it does not work :(

Comment: Again, the print statement gets executed but not the picture doesn't change

Comment: Please change your **userProfileImage**. This Should be a var instead of **static let

Comment: Hey I tried static var, doesn't work, and I cannot remove static cuz then I wont be able to access it with another view controller

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `setNeedsDisplay()` for update the imageview

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UserProfile.userProfileImage.image = UIImage(named: "profilePicture")
    UserProfile.userProfileImage.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use image literal

```
struct Downloads {

guard let profilePicURL = URL(string: profilePictureString) else {
    UserProfile.userProfileImage.image = imageLiteral(resourceName: "profilePicture")
    print("Profile picture set to default profile picture")
    return
}
// Some code
```

}

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer, but just tried it, doesn't work :(